# how to update the records in angular without using "id" in put method

Tags: angular, frontend, put, http-method

I am developing the mobile recharge website using angular,angular material,springboot ,this code is for admin, who can able to update the plans in website. And the problem is with the edit option. After clicking update button in edit ,instead of updating the values , it creates the new plan .Refer the output image below for clearance.

**update.ts**

```
    import { Component, Inject, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
    import { FormGroup,FormBuilder,Validators } from '@angular/forms';
    import { AdminApiService } from '../services/admin-api.service';
    import{ MatDialogRef,MAT_DIALOG_DATA } from '@angular/material/dialog'
    
    @Component({
      selector: 'app-add-plan',
      templateUrl: './add-plan.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./add-plan.component.css']
    })
    export class AddPlanComponent implements OnInit {
      PlanDetails !: FormGroup;
      actionBtn : string ="Save";
      constructor(private formBuilder:FormBuilder,
        private api: AdminApiService,
        private dialogRef: MatDialogRef<AddPlanComponent>,
        @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public editData: any) { }
      
    
    
      
      ngOnInit(): void {
        this.PlanDetails = this.formBuilder.group({
          planName:['',Validators.required],
          planPrice:['',Validators.required],
          planType:['',Validators.required],
          planOffers:['',Validators.required],
          planValidity:['',Validators.required],
          planDescription:['',Validators.required]
        });
    
        if(this.editData){
          this.actionBtn="Update";
          this.PlanDetails.controls['planName'].setValue(this.editData.planName);
          this.PlanDetails.controls['planPrice'].setValue(this.editData.planPrice);
          this.PlanDetails.controls['planType'].setValue(this.editData.planType);
          this.PlanDetails.controls['planOffers'].setValue(this.editData.planOffers);
          this.PlanDetails.controls['planValidity'].setValue(this.editData.planValidity);
          this.PlanDetails.controls['planDescription'].setValue(this.editData.planDescription);
        }
    
      }
    
      addPlan(){
        if(!this.editData){
          if(this.PlanDetails.valid){
            this.api.postPlan(this.PlanDetails.value)
            .subscribe({
              next:(res)=>{
                alert("product added succesfully");
                this.PlanDetails.reset();
                this.dialogRef.close('save');
              },
              error:()=>{
                alert("Error while adding the plan")
              }
            });
        }
        }else{
          this.updatePlan()
        }
      }
      
      updatePlan(){
        this.api.putPlan(this.PlanDetails.value)
        .subscribe({
          next:(res)=>{
            this.PlanDetails.reset();
            this.dialogRef.close('update');
          },
          error:()=>{
            alert("error on update");
          }
        })
        
      }
    
    }
```

**api.service.ts**

```
    import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
    import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
    import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment';
    
    @Injectable({
      providedIn: 'root'
    })
    export class AdminApiService { 
      private apiServerUrl=environment.apiBaseUrl;
      
      constructor(private http : HttpClient) { }
      
      postPlan(data: any){
        return this.http.post<any>(`${this.apiServerUrl}/admin-plan/add`,data);
      }
      getPlan(){
        return this.http.get<any>(`${this.apiServerUrl}/admin-plan/all`);
      }
      putPlan(data:any){
        return this.http.put<any>(`${this.apiServerUrl}/admin-plan/update`,data);
      }
      deletePlan(id:number){
        return this.http.delete<any>(`${this.apiServerUrl}/admin-plan/delete/`+id);
      }
    
    
      
    }
```

[image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/izsUF.png)

[image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ztWz.png)

Please refer the output image. When I am editing the price from 399 to 39,instead of updating the price ,it is adding new row in output.

can anyone please tell me how to update the particular value ,without creating new rows ,using angular.

how to update the records in angular without using "id" in put method

[Postman screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fuGPk.png).In that I have updated the price from 200 to 201.And It works fine.

Comment: Do you get new entry in database too?

Comment: The issue is not in angular. It is in api controller. Try hitting this api in postman and you will see the same result

Comment: While I am performing put operation in postman, it works correctly without adding the new database. But, when I test it in angular,it doesn't working

Comment: Attach screenshot of postman's request with body

Comment: You have to send id like you did in postman

Comment: I am new to angular,can u help me where to make changes

Answer (score 0):

Pass id along with form value

```
updatePlan() {
    this.api.putPlan({ id: this.editData.id, ...this.PlanDetails.value })
        .subscribe({
            next: (res) => {
                this.PlanDetails.reset();
                this.dialogRef.close('update');
            },
            error: () => {
                alert("error on update");
            }
        })
}
```